# Is it possible to devep web applications (PHP/Ruby) using Docker without PHP/Ruby on host?

Tags: docker

As in the question. Can you actually use Docker on top of Linux system (Ubuntu) that has NO `php` or `ruby` installed? I use `postgres` image for database and (of course) `postgres` package is not installed on my host.

I wonder if it is possible to use containers for development. How to overcome lack on `rails new`/`rails g` on host?

Answer (score 0):

Docker environment it's completely independent of your host - they have the own library, packages installed inside of them. If you want to run ruby/php inside docker, just download proper image which contains ruby/php or build own image.

For ruby check this link: https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/

Comment: Yes, I know that. The question is: is it possible to develop a web application inside a container without the need to mount a volume from outside? As in: use my code editor on host to code inside container. Because right now in order to do Rails app I need to: 1. create an app, using host's `rails` command. 2. code using host's code editor. 3. mount volume inside docker container.